# How to concatenate the column,when one column is having null value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement that,I have to concatenate fields,And if any field is null then i have to give space.

For Ex: **If Name value is not null**

```
SELECT Id||Name||number FROM NAMES;
```

o/p:
output:

```
1Tom3
2Lucy4
3Jack5
4Jane6
```

**If Name value is null**

```
SELECT Id||coalesce(Name,'')||number FROM NAMES;
```

output should be :

o/p:

```
1Tom3
2Lucy4
3    5
4Jane6
```

Can anyone please help me how we can do that,I tried multiple way but its not working

Comment: `coalesce(Name,' ')` will give one <space> character for null values.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I tried but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want four spaces if the `name` is `NULL`.  So that should be in the expression:

```
SELECT Id || coalesce(Name, '    ') || number
FROM NAMES;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,I tried but its not working

Comment: "it's not working" is totally devoid of actionable information.  Exactly what is not working? Are you not getting any spaces at all?  Getting more (or fewer) than you want?  Something else?

Comment: I tried with this way, case when NAME is null or NAME = '' then ' ' else NAME end,So now its working,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's applicable FOR ALL fields AND one SPACE per NULL value-column; the following should work.

```
SELECT NVL(ID,CHR(32)||NVL(NAME,CHR(32))||NVL(NUMBER,CHR(32)) FROM NAMES;
```